# Codeigniter: how to select_avg of multiple columns

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I just started with codeigniter and I'm stuck in my database query. I created a simple survey and I want to get the average of the columns. Right now I'm doing it like this to test it:

```
    for($x=1;$x<=5;$x++){
        $this->db->select_avg('q'.$x , 'averageq'.$x);
    }
    $this->db->where('sex','male');
    $query = $this->db->get('survey');
    $data = $query->row_array();
    print_r($data);
```

The survey will comprise of 30+ questions, is there a shorter way getting the the average of each column? something like:

```
select_avg('all columns in my answers table);
```

thank you

Comment: do you want avg of every column of answers table?

Comment: got to codeigniter documentation (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: @Aritra yes that's what I'm trying to do.